# Shopify doesnt seem to be running my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Im trying to implement a tracking  pixel. I've tested my ouput in several environments. Ive tried with or without wrapping the code in a function and deploying it with window.onload.

Here is a fiddle showing it working as intended as well. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83jCL/8/)

Basically, the code doesnt append the src to the image at all in shopify. Im at a total loss as to why. I checked the jquery library theyre loading, matched it etc. In theory this should fire flawlessly.

The code is placed in the checkout additional content and scripts box, as this is a purchase tracking link. Any help here would be much appreciated.

```
<img id="nanImg" style="display:none;" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nanigansLink () {
var emailTrim = $.trim("    {{customer.email}}   ");
var emailLower = emailTrim.toLowerCase();
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(emailLower);
var imageSrc = "https://api.nanigans.com/event.php?app_id=67997&type=purchase&name=main&user_id="+ hash + "&unique={{ order_number }}&qty[0]= {{ line.qty }}&sku[0]=REV1&value[0]=19900&ut1=" + hash;
var input = document.getElementById('nanImg');
input.src = imageSrc; }
window.onload = nanigansLink;
</script>
```

Comment: going to try with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', nanigansLink);` and see what happens. will post back if anything fires properly

Comment: Didnt work. Trying everything i can think of here

Comment: are you getting any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Keep in mind this code will only appear on the 'Thank you' page of the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Code i working fine for me, mightbe this is because of using unnecessary spaces.

```
var emailTrim = $.trim("    {{customer.email}}   ");
```

should be like

```
var emailTrim = $.trim("{{ customer.email }}");
//OR
//var emailTrim = $.trim("{{customer.email}}");
```